# Set returned object of https.get to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Looking to set the object that is retrieved from a `https.get` to a variable opposed to printing it to console. Attempting to use `Promises` to achieve this but it is just returning the function itself.

```
const https = require("https");
if(true){
const destinationsfinal = () => {
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            https
         .get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY', (resp) => {
             let data = '';

             resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                 data += chunk;
             });

             resp.on('end', () => {
             resolve(JSON.parse(data))
                 
             });
         })
         .on('error', (err) => {
             reject('Error: ' + err.message);
         });

})
 }
```

}

Comment: `desinationsfinal().then(() => { //save to some variable here}`

Comment: If you could use async await, things will be lot more easier for you.

Comment: @DaveRanjan Given that he's using a callback API in the first place, not really - `await` can replace `.then`, but it cannot replace the Promise constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to resolve the promise in order to get the result from your function (that is because it returns a Promise and not the result of this promise). To solve this problem you can do it either with then/catch or async/await.

**then/catch**:

```js
let result;
destinationsfinal()
  .then((data) => {
    result = data;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**async/await**:

```js
let result;
(async () => {
  try {
    result = await destinationsfinal();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of what your code does and why, and also separate these solutions into two separate code blocks